# Constantly changing random generator number

Tags: python

I am trying to write a programm in Python. The purpose of it is to generate random number from the given range. Then generate it again but the higher value within the range changes to the earlier generated number and again. The programm stops when it reaches or generates the lower bound.

I am currently stuck with it:

```
import random

l = int(input("Lower value: "))
h = int(input("Higher value: "))

n = int(random.randint(l, h))

print(n)

w = int(random.randint(l, n))

while w != l:
    input(w)
else:
    print("You won")
```

But the outcome looks like this:

```
7
3
3
3
```

Instead of:

```
7
5
3
3
2
You won
```

I just don't know what am I lacking or is the loop badly used.

Comment: I'm guessing the while loop is intended to repeat your code until you generate a number lower or equal to your lower bound, but the part of the code that does that isn't in the loop body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its quite simple actually. You need to loop the `w` to make it the new high value.
So this part is actually fine I added a `i` just for counting the loop iterations.

```
import random
i=1 

l = int(input("Lower value: "))
h = int(input("Higher value: "))

n = int(random.randint(l, h)) 
print("Random generated " + str(i)+ ":" ,n) #Just printing stuff
```

Now you want to set `w` as the "new higher value" that goes inside the loop. But take this into account, you want to compare `n` as it is the first generated value you created. So I'd use `!n` in the `while` statement.

```
while n != l:
    i=i+1  #this is just for counting the loop iterations.
    w = int(random.randint(l, n)) #you are generating a new radom number with n 
    print("Random generated " + str(i)+ ":" , w) #just printing stuff  
    n=w #assign n to set as higher value again in the next iteration. 

else:
    print("You won")
```

Then the output will look something like this:

```
Lower value: 1
Higher value: 10
Random generated 1: 6
Random generated 2: 5
Random generated 3: 3
Random generated 4: 1
You won
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you aren't reassigning a value to `w`. From what I understand, you just want to assign another random integer to `w` in each iteration of the `while` loop. To do so:

```py
lower, upper = int(input("Lower bound: ")), int(input("Upper bound: "))
n = random.randint(lower, upper)
print(n)
w = None
while w != lower:
    w = random.randint(lower, n)
    print(w)
print("You won")
```

Here's a sample run:

```py
Lower bound: 1
Upper bound: 10
2
5
9
7
6
4
5
8
1
You won
```